# Can we get coordinates (x,y) of winlogon screen for any resolution set in system? (as indicated in attached image )

Tags: c++, windows, automation, windows-authentication, credential-providers

[image: x,y coordinates of user tile shown on winlogn(credUI/secure logon) page]

I want to make auto login of a particular user when certain events happen when on any service running inside the system. 
CredentialProvider is used to fetch User & Password, but complete auto login does not work.
So I want to call Mousemove & mouseclick on x,y position on credential provider tile.

Custom CredentialProvider runs under winlogon, So any code in CredentailProvider will execute as winlogon, So can Active Accessibility User Interface methods used inside CredentailProvider and access Text / coordinates of user tile?

Comment: The winlogon cannot be scraped or tampered with by any application or service, you know that right?

Comment: This looks like the (secure) Windows 10 login screen. In what sort of context do you expect your code to run, that you can interact with this screen?

Comment: Custom CredentialProvider runs under winlogon, So any code in CredentailProvider will execute as winlogon, So can Active Accessibility User Interface methods used inside CredentailProvider and access Text / coordinates of user tile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your own credential provider you should be able to logon user automatically. You need to call *CredentialsChanged()* using *ICredentialProviderEvents* object you got on *Advice()*.

But if you want to use the crazy way (clicking the button and so on) you can get coordinates of that button using Active Accessibility or UI Automation.